# Examples of representations of Lie groups

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am dealing with representations of Lie groups, and as one knows, by the representation of a Lie group G, we refer to the following:

$1)$ (geometrical apect)

A representation of the Lie group $G$ on the (finite-dimensional complex) vector space $V$ is a continuous action $\phi: G$x$V \to V$ of $G$ on $V$such that for each $g \in G$ the translation $I_g: v \to \phi(g,v)$ is a linear map.

$2)$ (numerical aspect)

A matrix repesentation of $G$ is, simply, any continuous homomorphism $I: G \to GL(n,\mathbb C)$.

Understanding these two approaches, can someone give me two examples for these two definitions; one for each of them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any subgroup $G\le GL(n,\Bbb{C})$ acts on the space $V=\Bbb{C}^n$ by matrix multiplication (from the left). In this case $\phi$ is just matrix multiplication, and $I$ is the identity mapping $G\to GL(n,\Bbb{C})$. Would you like to see something more interesting, or will this (standard) example give you what you are looking for?

Comment: Also interesting is the algebraic aspect, that $\phi:G\rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ induces a Lie algebra representation $d\phi:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$, which can be studied with linear algebra.

Comment: Yes of course, I am interested in a bit more interesting examples. But of course these would work as well.